# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by Warning in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/www/example.com/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php:180) in
>   /home/www/example.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Comment: plese provide more information .. samepl of your code etc.. But in short .. your script already outputed some characters - and thus headers cannot be send as they already had been ... look for `echo` and `var_dump` etc..

Answer (score 0):

The most probable issue seems that someone has added malicious script to your wordpress files.

Their are two ways to solve this issue, both require ftp access.

1) Go to root/wp-includes/ and open class.wp-scripts.php file in editor. Go to line 180 and try to find the unusual code and delete it.

2) Download fresh wordpress installation from [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) and replace the respective file.